# Split string on matching patterns using regular expressions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split a string by matching some patterns using regex,
for instance i have `<span>Hello World</span>` and the result would be `["<span>", "Hello World", "</span>"]`

```js
// Tried this
console.log(arr.split(/(<*>)/));
// and this:
console.log(arr.split(/(^<$>)/));
```

Comment: [Regex is **NOT** a good tool to parse XML / HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5784924)

Comment: hah, @Nicolas you beat me to the share ^^

Comment: @Scrimothy this type of question is so frequent, i have it ready for copy and paste.

Comment: You can create a regex for very very simple cases but you would never be able to parse a full page.

Comment: @Nicolas you answer is Gold :D

Comment: How to parse string to html then?

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori If you are not using node you could just create an element add the text using `innerHtml` and then use the dom tree in any way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const a = `<span>Hello World</span>`; 

var c = a.split(/^(<.*>)(.*?)(<.*?>)$/g).filter(x => x);

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```js
  const s = `<span>Hello World</span>`; 
  const output = s.split(/(<\/?span>)/g).filter(Boolean);

  console.log(output);
```

Comment: `filter(Boolean)` ?

Comment: Thanks @nickzoum

Comment: This is incorrect as your forcing just the span tag in the split